# Can someone explain to me this `StaleDataException`

Tags: android, exception, staledataexception

Can someone explain to me this `StaleDataException`

```
07-11 19:58:23.298 E/AndroidRuntime( 1044): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 19:58:23.368 E/AndroidRuntime( 1044): android.database.StaleDataException: Access closed cursor
07-11 19:58:23.368 E/AndroidRuntime( 1044): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:217)
07-11 19:58:23.368 E/AndroidRuntime( 1044): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:84)
07-11 19:58:23.368 E/AndroidRuntime( 1044): at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:128)
```

When and how do we need to assure a requiry on the cursor, and why fails with this Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve information from a `Cursor` that has already been closed. You must verify whether the cursor is closed or not by using the [`isClosed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isClosed%28%29) method.

Comment: Can you please suggest me decent a way of fixing this issue. Currently am getting lot of staleDataException which i couldn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't close the cursor until CursorAdapter is no longer needed. So you can close it in onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();

     //Close the cursor
     cursor.close();
     //Close the database
     database.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was closing the cursor in the onStop() method. It turned out that the rotation of the screen was causing this code to run and hence give the StaleDataException.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activity.getContentResolver.query()` instead of `Activity.managedQuery()`. Because `managedQuery()` is deprecated. It works for me.